# Hidden password is being displayed when invoking the su command?

Tags: bash

This is the first time it has happened to me where I am using the su command and it actually displays the password on the terminal and doesn't stay hidden. Here is my code snippet:

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh -q username@74.11.11.11 "su -lc 'mkdir temp/'"
```

Code explanation: I am accessing a remote server and trying be root on that server to create a folder. In doing so I have to use the su command and it prompts me for the password. When I enter the password, it gets displayed and doesn't stay hidden.

Comment: This was also [crossposted on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001280/how-do-you-keep-the-password-hidden-when-invoked-during-the-su-command)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `sudo`.

`sshpass -p "password" ssh -q username@74.11.11.11 "sudo mkdir temp/"`

With sudo you could even run mkdir without a password. Run `visudo` and add this line:
`your_username ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/mkdir`. Note that this could potentially be a security risk, should your user account ever be compromised.

Futher, if it suits the use case of this command you could also set up public key authentication for SSH. You could then drop 'sshpass' and simply use `ssh -q username@74.11.11.11 "sudo mkdir temp/"`.